# Is thread time spent in synchronization too high?

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, concurrency, micro-optimization

Today I profiled one of my C# applications using the Visual Studio 2010 Performance Analyzer. Specifically, I was profiling for "**Concurrency**" because it seemed as though my app should have more capacity then it was demonstrating. The analysis report showed that the threads were spending ~70-80% of their time in a Synchronization state.

To be honest, I'm not sure what this means. Does this mean that the application is suffering from a live-lock condition?

For context... there are ~30+ long-running threads bound to a single AppDomain (*if that matters*) and some of the threads are very busy (Ex. `while(true) { _waitEvent.WaitOne(0); //do stuff }`).

I realize this is a fairly vague question... I guess I'm looking for some elucidation on the meaning the Synchronization state of threads. How much is too much, and why? Is ~75% really bad? Do I have too many threads? or should I just start looking in other areas?

Comment: My crystal ball says that you've got a machine with 8 cpu cores.  So you've always got 22 threads that are waiting for a chance to run.  22/30 * 100% = 73% idle.  You'll need more silicon.

Comment: What does your program do? What bottleneck are you using threads to solve?

Comment: @HansPassant: If threads are showing up in the "Synchronization" section of the threading performance report then they are *blocked* in a manner *not* related to disk, network, UI message pumps, page faults, preemption by another higher-priority thread, or deliberately sleeping the thread. Being in the Synchronization category is highly likely to be due to contention on a mutex of some sort; I doubt that the problem is due to processor saturation. Just the opposite seems likely to be true; I'd be willing to bet that in Joe's case the processor utilization is low.

Comment: Yeah, that's likely.  My crystal ball is a bit off this week.

Comment: Eric, you were correct... my CPU utilization was quite low.

Comment: That is highly characteristic of this problem. My "traffic" analogy is not quite right; you have thirty cars (threads), but only, say, four drivers. A car with a driver is driving; a car without a driver is either "blocked" at a stoplight, or "pre-empted" -- able to move forward if there is a driver, but there is not one available. When a car stops at a stoplight, the driver checks to see if there is any car that is *capable* of making progress that doesn't have a driver, and if there is one, runs over to it and starts driving it.

Comment: If you have low CPU utilization that means that of your 30 cars, 29 of them are stopped at a traffic light waiting for the 30th to get through the intersection. That 30th car has a driver. The other three drivers don't have a car capable of making progress that they can drive -- they're all blocked anyway, so there's no point. So they take a little nap until there is one, and hey, you've just spent four times too much for that computer; you have three idle cores.

Comment: If, in contrast, your *context switching cost* is extremely high *the drivers are spending all of their time running from car to car and no time driving them*. That could be characteristic of too many threads trying to work on too few processors; that's Hans Passant's scenario that he mentioned above.

Comment: It seems to me that the Synchronization % is actual CPU usage.  If the total CPU usage in task manager for this app is 10%, and if the Synchronization % of this app shown in ConcurrencyVisualizer is 75%, then your app uses 10% of 75% = 7.5% of the CPU for synchronization?  i.e. it would still be worth getting the Synchronization percentage down?

Comment: If Sync % is like the ConcurrencyVisualizer Sleep% which presumably does not use CPU cycles to sleep, then surely, in ConcurrencyVisualizer, a small Exec CPU % but high Sleep % and/or Synchronization % implies that the small Exec CPU % in fact corresponds to most of the task manager CPU %, and the Sleep/Synchronization % corresponds to almost none of the task manager CPU%.

Comment: So Question: Is Synchronization like Execution, using actual CPU work cycles , or is it like Sleep, not using actual CPU work cycles?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> I'm not sure what this means.

It means that the threads were on average spending 75% of their time waiting for another thread to finish some work.

> Does this mean that the application is suffering from a live-lock condition?

Maybe!

To clarify for readers unfamiliar with the term: a 'deadlock' is when two threads are both waiting for each other to finish, and therefore they wait forever. A 'live lock' is a situation where two threads are trying to avoid a deadlock, but due to their poor choices, spend most of their time waiting anyway. Imagine for example a table with two people, a fork and a knife. Both people wish to pick up both utensils, use them, and then put them down. Suppose I pick up the knife and you pick up the fork. If we both decide to wait for the other to put the utensil down, we are deadlocked. If we both realize that we're about to deadlock, and I put down the knife, and you put down the fork and *then I pick up the fork and you pick up the knife*, we are live-locked. We can repeat this process indefinitely; we're both working to resolve the situation, but we're not communicating effectively enough to actually resolve it quickly.

However, my *guess* is that you're not in a live-lock situation. My guess is rather that you simply have enormous contention on a small number of critical resources that can only be accessed by one thread at a time. Occam's Razor would indicate that you should assume the simple hypothesis -- lots of threads taking turns using a scarce resource -- rather than the complicated hypothesis -- a whole bunch of threads all trying to tell each other "no, you go first".

> There are ~30+ long-running threads bound to a single AppDomain (if that matters) and some of the threads are very busy (Ex. while(true) { _waitEvent.WaitOne(0); //do stuff }).

Sounds awful.

> I realize this is a fairly vague question.

Yes, it is.

> How much is too much, and why?

Well, suppose you were trying to drive across town, and you and every other driver in the city spent 75% of your time stopped at traffic lights waiting for other drivers. You tell me: is that too much, and why?  Spending an hour in traffic to drive for 15 minutes distance might be perfectly acceptable to some people and utterly unacceptable to other people. Every time I take SR 520 at rush hour I spend an hour in traffic to move a distance that should take 15 minutes; that wasn't acceptable to me so now I take the bus.

Whether this lousy performance is acceptable to you and your customers or not is your call. Fixing performance problems is *expensive*. The question you should be asking is how much profit you'll gain by taking on the expense of diagnosing and fixing the problem.

> Is ~75% really bad?

Your threads are taking four times longer than they need to. Doesn't seem too good to me.

> Do I have too many threads?

You almost certainly do, yes. 30 is a lot.

But that is completely the wrong technical question to ask in your situation. Asking "do I have too many threads?" is like trying to fix traffic congestion by asking "*does this city have too many cars?*" The right question to ask is "*why are there so many traffic lights in this city where there could be freeways?*"  The problem isn't the threads; **the problem is that they are waiting on each other instead of driving on through to their destinations without stopping.**

> should I just start looking in other areas?

How on earth should we know?

Comment: I'm still mulling over your answer... but... truth be told. I appreciate your directness and laughed out-loud while reading it. Thanks... nicely stated!

Comment: @JoeGeeky: Since you already have the profiler open, I'd spend some time using it to understand just why it is that your threads are spending so much time waiting on each other. Take a look at this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336027.aspx -- scroll down to the heading "Inter-thread Dependencies" and it will give you some advice on how to use the visualization tool that tells you which threads are waiting on what locks.  Good luck; these sorts of problems can be quite tricky to debug.

Comment: Thanks for the article, I'm reading through this now... Will take just a bit of time to digest. As first glance it would appear that maybe having a high Synchronization number; in and of itself; may not be a bad thing? I think I need to go back and look at my preemption numbers, etc...

Comment: @JoeGeeky: A high synchronization number is indicative that the program does not efficiently use the processing capabilities of multi-core machines. Is that a bad thing? It depends on whether your customers, who paid for, say, a four-core machine, will accept getting the performance of a one-core machine. Most customers expect that buying more cores will get them more performance; you might be disappointing them.

Comment: It also depends on what your program actually does, of course. If your program is a calculator and takes 4ms instead of 1ms to calculate something, it's not a problem. If it's a compiler and someone is sitting there waiting for it to compile, they probably bought their computer with the goal of making compilations faster, so they'd be pretty disappointed if it takes 4 minutes instead of one.

Comment: How certain are you that the CPU Synchronization row refers to the "spending [X]% of their time waiting for another thread to finish some work"?   The row is CPU%, which implies work done by the CPU, not idle time spent waiting.

Comment: @Markus: I will refer you to the documentation, and encourage you strongly to look it up yourself next time rather than using SO as an extremely inefficient search engine. "When a thread is marked as blocked on synchronization, one of these things is implied:The execution of the thread may have resulted in a call to a well-known thread synchronization API such as EnterCriticalSection() or WaitForSingleObject()...."

Comment: ...The API matching algorithm cannot be totally comprehensive, and therefore some APIs that could be mapped to other categories may also appear as synchronization because a frame in the call stack eventually reached an underlying kernel blocking primitive that was mapped to this category.To understand the underlying cause for a thread blocking event, carefully examine the blocking call stacks and profile reports."

Answer (score 2):

Without really knowing the structure of your program, I can only really tell you what *Synchronization* means in relation of threads.  I can't really tell you what the problem in your program is.

**Synchronization** basically means that you *coordinate* so to speak the concurrent running of threads when actions have to be taken on resources that are shared by these threads, in order to avoid **corruption of your data**.

If you have an `string`, for example, that your two threads are writing to, then, if you didn't have thread synchronization (ie using AutoResetEvents or Semaphores, etc) then one thread could be in the middle of altering the string in some fashion, be interrupted by the OS (maybe it's time slice was up), and now the second thread may be starts reading from this string, which is in an indeterminate state.  This will wreak having with your program, so in order to avoid such things, and many other possible errors that can be caused by threading, you **synchronize** access to the shared resource, by **locking** it, so that only one thread at a time can write/read to/from it, and any other thread wanting to do so *while* the other is doing so, has to **wait until our first thread** has released the lock it holds.

This is, in a very simplified explanation, what thread synchronization means and what it is for.
There is many more things that come with threading, but that's the subject of an entire book.

As to what your "Synchronization State of Threads" may mean, I would guess it means that a lot of threads spend their time waiting on other threads that are holding some shared resource.

Essentially that means your program is really not working *concurrently*, but is doing things in *serial*, as threads are spending their time *waiting on other threads*. This means that the program is not written very well to really work concurrently, which, by the way is not necessarily an easy feat to achieve, **depending on the situation**, obviously.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Given the statement in your last paragraph (*e.g. "Essentially that means your program is really not working concurrently, but is doing things in serial"*), could this be a case of just having too many threads given the number of processors (*and/or cores*) available in the target environment? Or is it possible the '*busy*' threads are just demanding so much they are causing all this extra syncronization? Btw, I totally appreciate your entering comment, just wondering when the Sync. percentage may start to signal a problem. I'm just not sure if ~75% smells like something is wrong or not.

Comment: IMO, 75% seems quite high, but I'm it's really hard to say without seeing code.  It *could* be that you have too many threads for the No of cores available, but it could be anything else too.  Very hard to determine.  I suggest you read up on threading and thread synch, cause only *understanding* those things well, will get you anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways that thread synchronization can kill performance:

1. The instructions for implementing synchronization take time to execute, especially for synchronization routines that require a transition to kernel mode such as Thread.Sleep().  In the worst case, a lone thread making frequent calls to synchronization routines introduces a whole lot of overhead for no real benefit.
2. Whenever more than one thread needs exclusive access to a resource at the same time, at least one thread gets stuck waiting.  The worst case scenario here is that there is some central resource which everyone needs to access frequently.  In this case, multithreaded code is in serious danger of becoming an expensive, slow, and complicated way to have one thread working at a time.

As for how much is too much:  Synchronization is something that takes time but doesn't really do any useful work.  Therefore, from a performance perspective the ideal amount of synchronization is always zero.  Hence the high value that is placed on shared-nothing architectures and [immutable data structures](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/immutability/).  Both are techniques to help organize code in a way that eliminates or reduces the need for synchronization.

Of course the world isn't ideal so some amount of synchronization is usually inescapable. But even then it should be done using the lightest-weight constructs possible. For example, don't use a lock statement when a method in [Interlocked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.aspx) will do.  Or reduce the frequency with which it needs to happen by designing threads to send work product to a central data structure in batches, rather than making a lot of high-frequency updates.

Comment: Is Interlocking actually faster then a lock or is the contention mitigation different from a lock. If I remember correctly, interlocks create a full fence (e.g. four memory barriers). I always assumed that a full fence was just as expensive as a full lock. Do I have this wrong?

Comment: According to Microsoft's [Managed Threading Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c9txz50.aspx) article, it is faster. I haven't delved into the implementation details, but my experience tends to confirm it.